# Java Incompatible operand types void and Class<Void>

Tags: java, assert

I'm implemebting some lists in java, but I encountered this problem.

```
assertTrue( list.remove( "A" ) == void);
```

Comment: What you wanna do? I guess you mean null instead of void. void is an keyword in Java: Since JDK 1.1, Java provides us with the Void type. Its purpose is simply to represent the void return type as a class and contain a Class<Void> public value. It's not instantiable as its only constructor is private.

Comment: Yeah, I think you want `null` there.

Comment: But `list.remove(Object)` returns a boolean. You should use `assertTrue(list.remove( "A" )` (or `assertFalse`).

Comment: How is this Q still at a zero score after all these responses? There isn't anything in OP that even remotely resembles a question here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. list.remove(Obj) returns you a boolean variable. Which returns true if the element was present and removed, and false if the element is not present.
2. You cannot compare a type(keyword) in Java.

If you are looking to check if an element was removed, you can check like
`list.remove("A") == false`
which will do the same thing.

Comment: "or was not removed." This is not allowed by the interface specification. If the element is present, it must remove the element and return true, or throw an exception. It will only return false if the element was not present.

Comment: True. My miss. Thanks for taking my attention to it Andy.

Comment: Nearly always better to say `!list.remove("A")`, or in this case, `assertFalse`.